# VTK headers in C++

Tags: c++, vtk, paraview

I am starting to learn about VTK. I would like to generate VTK files with C++ for later post-processing with Paraview.

To compile the c++ code with the vtk headers I need to create a cmake file, which then generates a Makefile. I wonder if there is a simpler way. For example installing the headers in some folders.

Sorry for my ignorance, I am also quite new in C++.

Cheers

Comment: Using `CMake` to generate solutions for `vtk` is the simpler way. If you don't there is extra work you need to setup object factories and link to many libraries depending on what options you want. I don't recommend this unless you are a `c++` expert.

Comment: https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_6_Migration/Factories_now_require_defines